# How to run Arduino codes in Java netbeans?

Tags: arduino-ide, java

Having a hard time searching the net on how to run arduino codes on java. Can somebody please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Arduino code is `C`, not `Java`. So you'd need to translate it to java.

Comment: It may help if you explain what your intended outcome is.  Your PC (or even an raspberry pi) doesnt have the same GPIO as an arduino. If your code does not interface with any of that, and you are just wanting to port the c++ code to java, there are ways to do that(this would not be the place to look for help with that though)  But maybe try and explain what it is your actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I would like to send sms using arduino and java. But i can't do it. I already made a communication between them but still it doesn't work. What should i do? And what do you guys think of my mistake?

Comment: We cannot say anything about your mistake, since you didn't gave us any information. The Arduino itself  cannot run java. I assume you try to let a java program on your PC communicate with the Arduino. Then just google for java serial communication

Comment: What i want is to send sms using arduino and java

Answer (score 5):

Java is a programming language. Arduino is a platform that is mostly accessed by the C++ programming language. You cannot run "Arduino code" in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino can't run Java. Full stop.